# Time and date echo from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have this question:

I have selected date & time from the table & echoed them just fine but I don't like the date & time format that is echoed. Here in Central-Southern Africa, we are used to 24hrs (like 16:30hrs instead of 4:30pm etc).

Here is the code:

```
("SELECT * FROM me order by 1 DESC LIMIT 0,10");
$date = $run_post['date'];

$time = $run_post['time'];
```

And them I do this:

```
echo $date;
```

and it gives me **2015-11-13** but I want **13th November 2015**
and then

```
echo $time;
```

giving me **2015-11-13 12:53:43** but want like **16:30:00 hrs** format.

Finally, I also want to echo my (UTC+02:00) Cairo Time zone. Currently it is giving me -2hrs

Comment: <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($time)) ?> - have a look here for more info - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You need to set your default time zone using `date_default_timezone_set()` function ([see this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)). Here's the list of [available time zones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your default time zone is set to UTC. If you want to display time as per your time zone(UTC+02:00), then you can do something like this:

```
function display_time($time){
    $unixdatetime = strtotime($time) + 7200;
    return strftime("%d %B %Y, %H:%M %p",$unixdatetime);
}
```

And when you call this *display_time* function, for example,

```
echo display_time($run_post['time']);
```

then it would display,

```
13 November 2015, 14:53 PM
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers. This is working just fine but the only problem is that since I have to display more than one post from the table, it is giving me this error after displaying the first post correctly with my desired date & time zone; Fatal error: Cannot redeclare display_time() (previously declared in.....

Comment: That's because you're trying to declare the `display_time(){ ... }` function more than once. Keep the function definition as it is and call the function with different parameters, like `echo display_time($time1)`, `echo display_time($time2)` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually its a commenting system so the posts come as people make comments and then display comment post date and time and that is why it been tricky for me to work it out. It has to echo date & time for each post as people post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the DateTime Class as you can set the timezone in it.

Example with Timezone Europe/London:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-11-13 12:53:43', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $date->format('d\t\h F Y') . "\n";
echo $date->format('H:i:s') . 'hrs';
```

[How to add Timezone to DateTime](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.settimezone.php)

Comment: Thanks. This helped put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

format method of DateTime class is what you need.

```
$date = new DateTime($run_post['time']);
echo $date->format('d\t\h\,F Y');
```

Will echo something like 13th, November 2015)

You have the documentation of how to format in

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks. This helped put it all together